# Format a XMLGregorianCalendar with Italian date format(dd/mm/yyyy) with no time

Tags: java, calendar, date-formatting, gregorian-calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am trying to convert a `java.util.Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar` in Italian format (dd/mm/yyyy) with no time. Whatever I try the output always prints `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
   GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
   XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
           cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
           DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);   
   System.out.println(xmlDate);
```

I am a consumer of SOAP web-service, and the date attribute is defined as `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Please advise how can I change the code to get the output with format (dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need an `XMLGregorianCalender`. It will not, cannot give you what you ask for. Instead you need a `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter italianDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(Locale.ITALIAN);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
    String formattedDate = date.format(italianDateFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

When I ran this code today, the output was:

> 21/01/19

The difference from what you ask for is the two digit year, `19`. If instead of `FormatStyle.SHORT` we use `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`, we get four digit year, but the month as a three letter abbreviaiton:

> 21-gen-2019

The advantage is that the code lends itself very well to internationalization: you just need to change the locale to get proper code for some other language and country. If you do need `21/01/2019` (with four digit year), specify the format explicitly using a pattern:

```
    DateTimeFormatter italianDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
```

> 21/01/2019

### What’s wrong with using `XMLGregorianCalendar`?

When you call `System.out.println(xmlDate)`, you are implicitly calling `toString` on your `XMLGregorianCalendar`. When it hasn’t got time and zone offset, `toString` always generates `yyyy-MM-dd` format, there is no way you can change that. On the other hand you can have any format you like in a `String`. Next obstacle is, there is no formatter that can format an `XMLGregorianCalendar` directly. You would need to convert to a different type, like `ZonedDateTime`, for example, first. Since you only want the date, neither the time of day nor the time zone, it’s simpler and easier to start out from `LocalDate` from the start. Not least for those reading and maintaining your code after you.

Your question mentions `java.util.Date` and your code uses `GregorianCalendar` too. Both of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, fully replaced by java.time, the modern Java date and time API. So I suggest you don’t use them.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Actually i am am a consumer of SOAP web-service and the date attribute is defined as XMLGegorianCalendar...

Comment: But when the `XMLGregorianCalendar` is passed through SOAP, it doesn’t have any format. @user1711472 Are you sending the `XMLGregorianCalendar`to the web service or receiving it from there?

Comment: I am using it to send the data to another application which in turn expecting the format as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Either you misunderstood or they have impossible requirements. Nobody in the world can send them an `XMLGregorianCalendar` in that format. As I said, it doesn’t exist. You may want to quote their specs in your question so we can help you decipher.