# Format instance of XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, jaxb, datetime-format, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have an instance of `XMLGregorianCalendar` with date format as

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

I need an instance of an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with

```
yyyy-MM-dd':'HH:mm:ss
```

date format.  Is it possible?

I need to set this date in XML using JAXB where schema mandates that the field be `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a XMLGregorianCalendar with Italian date format(dd/mm/yyyy) with no time \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294275/format-a-xmlgregoriancalendar-with-italian-date-formatdd-mm-yyyy-with-no-time)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the object of `XMLGregorianCalendar` to an object of `ZonedDateTime` which you can format in the desired format using `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        String givenDateTimeString = "2020-11-08T13:05:46";
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(givenDateTimeString);
        System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime();

        String formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd':'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(zdt);

        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-11-08T13:05:46
2020-11-08:13:05:46
```

Now, you can use the string, `formatted` in your XML.

**Note:** A date-time object is supposed to store the information about date, time, timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. You can format a date-time object into a **`String`** with the pattern of your choice using date-time formatting API.

- The date-time formatting types (e.g. `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` etc.) for the modern date-time types is in the package, `java.time.format`.
- The date-time formatting types (e.g. `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.text.DateFormat` etc.) for the legacy date-time types is in the package, `java.text`.

Comment: I can format date when it is a String.  The trouble is I have to use XMLGregorianCalendar due to jaxb binding and xml schema constraint.  It seems that the only way to get the date printed in desired format is to change xml schema, so it accepts String.

Comment: @Lidia - [You can NOT create a formatted Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664791/10819573)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The whole point in `XMLGregorianCalendar` is to provide dates and times in a format required by XML, and the format you are asking about is not allowed in XML. So what you are asking for is prevented on purpose.

If your requirement is an `XMLGregorianCalendar`, then you will have to live with the format printed from its `toString` and `toXMLFormat` methods (the two return the identical strings). I also don’t see why you should not be happy with that. This format fulfils the XML specification.

PS While `toString()` and `toXMLFormat()` return strings in XML format, i consider it wrong to say that the `XMLGregorianCalendar` *has got* this format. Its internal representation is quite different (and nothing we should care about). I consider it more correct to say that *an `XMLGregorianCalndar` cannot have a format*.

**Link:** [An answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485250/5772882) treating more thoroughly why you can have no date-time object with a format. I am using `Date` as an example, but what I write is fully valid for `XMLGregorianCalendar` too, and I do mention `XMLGregorianCalendar` at the end.